# Image helper unwanted resizing

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image

When I use my image-tag helper the image on the page is always smaller than the size of the image.  Is this a rails thing or am I overlooking something?  Even when setting image height to 100%, I can't get the full sized image. Any ideas??

Comment: I know I can manually put in the size, and add height and width stylings of 100% doesn't help.  I need it to display as the size of the image that was uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the image size is predefined in your stylesheet/css, take a look there.

Or you could try: image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", height: '32', width: '32')

Resource is here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
    <img src="img_location" alt="" style="width:100%; Height:100%;"/>
```

If your image size predefined by your css then it solve.